# How to use bitmap font in Text Mesh?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I have already make a bitmap font, include a ftn file and a png sprite.

I can use this on UGUI by creating fontsettings with "Custom Font", but how can I use it on Text Mesh or 3D Text?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer my own question AGAIN, AND AGAIN!

Find the solution from a book. Just change the custom font material's shader.

I'm not good at shader, just copy:

```
Shader "Custom/My3DFont" {
Properties {
    _Color ("Main Color", Color) = (1, 1, 1, 0.5)
    _MainTex ("Base (RGB) Trans (A)", 2D) = "white" {}
}

SubShader {
    Tags {"Queue"="Transparent" "IgnoreProjector"="True" "RenderType"="Transparent"}
    LOD 100

    ZWrite Off
    Blend SrcAlpha OneMinusSrcAlpha

    Pass {
        Material {
            Diffuse [_Color]
        }


        Lighting Off Cull Off ZTest Always ZWrite Off Fog { Mode Off }

        SetTexture [_MainTex] {
            constantColor [_Color]
            combine texture * constant
        }
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

bit map font on text mesh you just need get bitmap font importer from asset store and use tools like littera to create bitmap font from real font ex. ttf, then import the result of bitmap font and xml from littera to unity, then on textmesh component you set font parameter with font asset, and meshrenderer material with material from that font you just imported and set shader to unlight->transparent. done !